# Setuptools installing code from git submodules

Tags: pip, setuptools, setup.py, pypi, distutils

I have a Python library I am trying to package for PyPi which contains several git submodules pointing to external repositories. Something like:

```
MyLibrary
 - setup.py
 - MyLibrary
   - __init__.py
   - my_code1.py
   - my_code2.py
   - submodules
     - __init__.py
     - git submodule https://www.github.com/external/repository1
        - repository1_code.py
     - git submodule https://www.github.com/external/repository2
        - repository2_code.py
```

My `setup.py` file looks something like:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='MyLibrary',
    ...
    packages=find_packages(),
    ...,
    install_requires=["numpy", "scipy"]
)
```

The problem I am having is when I use pip to install this library, all my code and subfolders get installed fine, but the submodules are missing; they are not initialized/pulled in and don't appear inside the installed folder, neither the submodule folders nor the inner code (e.g `repository1_code.py`).

Is there some way to instruct `setup.py` to expand the submodules, i.e. `git submodule update --init --recursive` before installing the code?

Comment: do your submodules have `__init__.py` at their root? (it's necessary for `find_packages` to descend into them)

Comment: Thank you, this is one solution I didn't think of.

Comment: did that work? should I convert this to an answer?

Comment: You could probably give [`find_namespace_packages()`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#find-namespace-packages) a shot as well. It is less picky about `__init__.py` so it might work for your use case, but of course it has side effects as well.

Answer (score -3):

One solution, thanks to the top comment to the question, is to fork all of the submodules and place an `__init__.py` in all of the folders needed. This isn't optimal though because I'd rather not have to fork and modify the submodules, but use the originals.

Another solution is instead of using `find_packages()`, to simply explicitly write out all of the folders in the submodules instead. This is a bit inconvenient but works very well, and seems to be the best solution I've found so far.